# Smooth rendering of bitmap fonts

Tags: fonts, bitmap, pdftex

I would like to use the Concrete Math font in LaTeX, which is a bitmap font. The rendering with `pdflatex` is naturally poor-quality with jagged edges.

My solution so far has been to generate a DVI file and then convert to PDF using Linux's `dvipdf`. This tool effectively traces and smooths the edges of the glyphs and the end result is beautiful. However, using the DVI output format (with `latex`) causes a host of other problems with including figures, etc. For instance, you can't include `.png` or `.pdf` figures when using plain LaTeX.

Is there a way to somehow get the same bitmap font-smoothing effect in `pdflatex`? or via an intermediate format that still allows you to include at least `.png` figures?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set up in order that Metafont uses a high resolution device for producing the fonts; this should be run with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{concrete}

% MF mode dpdfezzz is for 8000dpi
\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}
\pdfpkresolution=8000

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some test text with\\
\textit{italic} and \textsl{slanted}.
\end{document}
```

Here's what appears on my screen at almost maximum zoom

[image]

You see that there's no jagged letter. Compare with what's obtained when the resolution and mode are the default

[image]

Load the images on a separate browser window or tab and maximize them to see the full comparison.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the default dpi for this font? And what are the possible values one can set for pdfpkresolution?

Comment: @Atcold There's no “default dpi”. This only depends on the output device. You need to look in `modes.mf` to see what's available.