# Smooth concrete math

Tags: fonts

This question is linked to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132238/smooth-rendering-of-bitmap-fonts). I want concrete math to be smooth. Following the answer of egreg, I obtain an arithmetic overflow. I think this is due to the 8000dpi specified in the answer. In fact, if I use lower resolution, for example by means of:

```
\pdfpkmode{linotzzh} 
\pdfpkresolution=2540
```

I succeed in obtaining higher resolution font (with respect to the 600dpi fonts, that are default ones in my knowledge), and actually the above specified 2540dpi resolution is the highest that I can obtain without incurring in the overflow. The question is: is there a way to avoid the arithmetic overflow? (I am using TexLive 2013.)

Comment: I tried the same example, adding also some math, with 12pt main point size and `\Huge`, not getting any overflow. In TeX Live 2013 and 2014. The fonts created have `.19904pk` extension. It's painfully slow, but it works.

Comment: You are totally right Enrico. In the attempt of compiling my thesis, I obtained that overflow, and I thought I would have obtained the same error with the MWE in the link above. I am now compiling each chapter separately in order to understand what is the actual problem... Anyway, thank your for your reply and for the solution using `\pdfpkresolution`, which is amazing :) (I will upvote the answer in the link once I will have the minimum required reputation :) )

Comment: Problem identified: the problem is, needless to say, very crazy ;) I have problem to map `\varnothing`. I bypassed the problem by replacing `\varnothing` with `\emptyset`... (initially, I replaced `\emptyset` with `\varnothing` because I don't like the `\emptyset` symbol, but, it's ok, this is a patch that works for now...).

Comment: What bugs me is that I've seen a pdf with smooth Concrete fonts (I think it wasn't on the Font Catalogue, but my mind says it was something similar). And after that I haven't found anything, but it must exist *somewhere*.

Comment: Maybe using Computer Modern in ttf ([here](http://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/)) and LuaLatex?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved in an unspecified way.

Comment: Actually it does not overflow in a MWE, by following the answer in the link (i.e. using `\pdfpkmode{dpdfezzz}\pdfpkresolution=8000`), and the original problem was due to `\varnothing`. Don't know the cause but that was the problem. It's ok to close anyway.